# Which is the best approach make responsive layouts in react native

Tags: react-native

Which is the best approach make responsive layouts in react native

Comment: React Native encourages 'responsive' layouts, through the use of their flexbox model provided by the Yoga layout system. It's very similar to how flexbox works on the web.

Answer (score 0):

use react-native Dimension Api.

it provides features like : 
1. set
2. get
3. addEventListener
4. removeEventListener

Add dimension event listener "change" in constructor.
everytime change listener is called check for Dimension.get('window').width/height 
and set you CSS state accordingly.

to seperate iOs and android react-native provides "platform" api, using which we can load  components for different device as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex for the style and you can also use this two functions based on iPhone 7's height and width.

Just use them when you need to set a responsive size somewhere.

```
const deviceWidth = () => Dimensions.get('window').width;
const deviceHeight = () => Dimensions.get('window').height;

function normalizeWidth(width) {
    const ratio = width / 375;
    return deviceWidth() * ratio;
}

function normalizeHeight(height) {
    const ratio = height / 667;
    return deviceHeight() * ratio;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [react-native-responsive-layout](https://github.com/axilis/react-native-responsive-layout) which I find very easy to use.